# Python pandas cross tab order

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I am analyzing a data set and i am trying to add one feature to the reporting process/script: once the cross tab is created, i merge in data details and i would like to reindex, but using relative value and position them within the below reindex list from newest to oldest:

```
df11:

Date_Viewed          Doc_ID
2018-04-01 00:56:00   1234
2018-04-01 00:56:02   1234
2018-04-02 03:29:46   5678
2018-04-02 10:12:16   5678

df11 = (pd.crosstab(df11['Doc_ID'], df11['Date_Viewed'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y'))
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis([None],axis=1)
    .merge(df5, how = 'left', on='Doc_ID')
    .sort_values('count', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    )
print(df11)

Doc_ID  05/2018  06/2018  07/2018  08/2018  count  SubType  Name
1234     327      383      290      241    1622    Report   Revenue
5678     530      182      262      197    1503    Report   Profit


#this is the only way i have found to be able to reindex them(create a new DF and then use an absolute reference to move the date columns around)
df12 = pd.DataFrame()
df12 = df11
df12.index.names = [None]
df12 = df12.reindex(['Doc_ID', 'Name', 'SubType',  '08/2018','07/2018','06/2018','count'], axis=1)
```

Any help you can provide to either of these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use df11 = df11.reindex(... You shouldn't need to create df12.  What problem are you facing when you try do it without creating a new dataframe?

Comment: @Scott, you are correct, my mistake, my original try had incorrect syntax.  Any thoughts on how to apply this reindex statement with a relative reference to the dates from most recent to oldest within the same order as mentioned above?  My hope would be to not have to go in and type over existing code each time i run the report- thanks again for your help!

Comment: try:  Hard coding for this number of months `[c[0]] + [c[-1]] + [c[-2]] + c[4:0:-1].tolist() + [c[-3]]` or this for dynamic with different amount of months `[c[0]] + [c[-1]] + [c[-2]] + c[c.str.contains('\d{2}\/\d{4}')][::-1].tolist() + [c[-3]]' where `c = df.columns`

Comment: @Scott thank you very much!  I will check this out tonight!  I appreciate your help!